# CSS properties that do not affect the element visually

Tags: javascript, css

In a Web App built with Angular, I load a very large dictionary and I also display large contents. When a word has a definition, I style it with a `border-bottom: 1px dotted green`.
I do this with a custom `<style>` tag that I build when the dictionary has loaded. The generated CSS looks like this:

```
[data-word="lorem"],[data-word="ipsum"] { border-bottom: 1px dotted green; }
```

(Yes, all words are splitted in single span with a data-word attributes)

I then use event delegation and check the `getComputedStyle`/`borderBottomColor` of the clicked word to see if that word has a definition or not.

**The problem:**

I would like to set a CSS property that will contains the definition ID, that I can extract from `getComputedStyle`. BUT, that CSS property must not change the element visually. Maybe there are a property that I can "partially" set, that is "valid" but won't render anything.

**The question:**

Which CSS attributes can I use? It must be available on mobile/tablet, both Android and iOS.

I am not looking for a better approach, I am already relying on heavy directives for that App. The same words may appear multiple times in the texts. I would like to avoid looping through all the words.

Also, there is a small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgLxL/) playground to play with.

Thank you very much.

**Edit:**

I have tried with the outline attribute which worked on my desktop. On my mobile though, it was way too slow. The mobile chrome must be doing calculations. Please note that I have been from `outline: 1px solid transparent;` to `outline: 1063px solid transparent;`. Any tips on what attribute I could use instead? I have changed all `px` values to `1` and it worked fine. It must hate too large `px` values.

**Edit:**

It was working with the `transition-duration` until I applied classes on those words. Sometimes I had to wait a few seconds before the effect of the class was shown. I need another attributes.

Comment: how about `outline: 0px solid transparent`?  Should be invisible enough

Comment: why not just set another data-* attribute that is what they are there for, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Comment: @PatrickEvans when the spans are generated with the data-word attribute, they aren't "aware" of the dictionary.

Comment: @JosephMarikle this seems to work for now. I can set outline: IDpx solid transparent. But I don't know how that will behave when the ID will be in the 1000s, I don't want to click on the "wrong" words. I don't know if the words will overlap.

Comment: @JosephMarikle write your comment as an answer. I will do further tests today but it does works in my browser for now.

Comment: You could use printing elements like `orphans` and `widows` too

Comment: Change the overflow property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
font-family: 'Open Sans',​ Helvetica,​ Arial, '808', ​sans-serif;
```

along with this regex

```
window.getComputedStyle(e.target).fontFamily.match(/\d/g).join('')
```

to extract the ID `808`

Answer (score 1):

One css style that is unlikely to be used as often is outline.  (syntax is the same as border)

```
outline: 0px solid transparent
```

### EDIT:

In retrospect it appears this is not the best approach.  I assume it slowed down the phone because while it didn't show the outline, it still rendered it.  With outlines getting into the 1000s it became too slow to be practical.  Using `transition-duration` works better.

Comment: From all the comments, this is the only one suggestion that works on my browser.

Comment: It does work. But for some reasons on my mobile it is really slow. It must calculate something with the outline attribute. It's not because my CSS generated is too large: I commented out the outline and it's fast with a little over a thousands [data-word] attributes. Even with those attributes chained for the border-bottom, my mobile render it well. Do you have any ideas of what I could use instead of outline?

Comment: I have tried with outline: 1px solid transparent for every of my [data-word] and it worked well. I must use an attribute that won't lag when I reach the 1000s of px.

Comment: @Cybrix how about `transition-duration` (javascript value is transitionDuration)?  That should allow you values into the 1000s without problems.

Comment: Perfect. I haven't tested with a iOS device but it's working on my Android mobile. Thank you. Do you want to update your answer above so I can accept it.

Comment: In my code, I have to apply some classes in some special occasion and the transition-duration delay the effect visually. I need another attribute. Any tips? (I have added this to the question)

Comment: @Cybrix honestly, at this point I would say the hack is not worth the effort.  I know you aren't looking for a better approach, but this approach has a couple knocks against it.  1) It's not working and 2) CSS was not designed to store data.  I don't have enough information to advise a better approach, but I'm not seeing a way to use CSS to store the ID.  One last thing you can do, though, is open up a page in chrome, enter the JS console and type `document.body.style` then hit enter.  There you will see a bunch of styles to choose from.  Not sure it you'll find one that works for you though.